# Parsing Object to Integer

Tags: java, parsing, object, integer

I don't understand what exactly the brackets `[]` do in this code `Integer[]` while parsing `new Objects`

```
 private Integer data[]=(Integer[]) new Object[10];//works fine

 private Integer data[]=(Integer) new Object[10];//error
```

Comment: Isn't that simple, you are trying to parse an Array to single object in latter one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`private Integer data[]=(Integer) new Object[10]; //I'm a C programmer :)!`

Is identical to:

`private Integer[] data=(Integer) new Object[10];`

Now you can better see that `data` is an **array** of `Integer`s.

`data` is of type `Integer[]`, you can't cast `new Object[10];` to `Integer` if the type of the variable in the left side is `Integer[]`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that `(Integer) new Object[10];` ie `(Integer)` will corresponding on every `new Object[10]`

Comment: btw `Upvote` for `//I'm a C programmer :)!` even though I don't have enough reputation for that action :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll read the code for you:

Line 1:

- `new Object[10]` - create a new array for 10 references to Object instances.
  The references are all null when that has completed.
- `(Integer []) ...` - tell the compiler that it should assume the array of Object references to actually be an array of Integer references, ie an array of references to instances of Integer.
- `private Integer data [] = ...` - keep the array we just created in a private reference variable called data, and assume data references an array of Integer.

Line 2:

- `(Integer)` - tell the compiler to make one Integer reference of the array of Object instances. That can't be done, because there is no way to turn an array into only one object.

To sum up:

The brackets in **X []** indicate **array of references to X**.

And **(Y) foo** reads *assume foo actually is an instance of type Y*.

Answer (score 0):

Array of objects has to be cast to `Integer[]` not to `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an instance of `data` array in the first case. But, in the 2nd case, you are trying to assign array to `Integer` whereas it is expecting it to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable `data` is `Integer[]` (array of Integers). It would be clearer if you used the traditional style of declaring arrays:

```
private Integer[] data = ...
```

So, the first line casts the expression to the type of the variable (`Integer[]`), whereas the second line casts it to `Integer`, which is not the type of `data`, hence the compilation error.

Note that the second line, although it compiles, doesn't make much sense. You should simply use

```
private Integer[] data = new Integer[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is casting the array of object to array of integer to allow the assignment.